# Check if email already exist error undefined index: user_id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a validation on an email field when i want to edit a user on a modal popup. The email filed is filled with the user email and when i do the validation it says the email has already been used. So I've decided to filter all the emails from the database using an array and excluding the user email from the array. It seems fine if i set the user id variable manually but i can't get the user id dynamically from the form and i wish someone can help. 
I believe the problem is here:

```
url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
```

Many thanks

**This is my html form:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id='EditUserModal' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica informazioni cliente</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="formedituser" action="../controllers/ctrl_admin_user_app/ctrl_admin_update_user_details.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-body">

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Nome Cliente
                        <span class="required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i>       
                            <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserici il nome del cliente" name="firstName">
                        </div>             
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Cognome Cliente
                          <span class="required"> * </span>
                          </label>
                          <div class="input-icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i>       
                              <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci il cognome del cliente" name="lastName">
                          </div>             
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Cliente
                        <span class="required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>       
                            <input type="text" id="userEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci email cliente" name="userEmail">
                        </div>             
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Telefono Cliente
                        <span class="required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="userTel" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci telefono utente" name="userTel"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Codice Fiscale</label>
                      <div class="input-icon">                           
                          <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>                       
                          <input type="text" id="userFiscalcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci codice fiscale" name="userFiscalcode">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Data di nascita</label>
                        <div class="input-icon">   
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="userBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci la data di nascita" name="userBirth"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Documento di identità</label>
                      <div class="input-icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
                          <input type="text" id="userDocument" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci documento del cliente" name="userDocument">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6" id="showrole">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Ruolo Cliente
                   <span class="required"> * </span>
                  </label>
                  <select class="form-control bs-select" id="userRole" name="userRole">
                   <option value="client">Cliente</option>
                   <option value="admin">Amministratore</option>

                  </select>

                 </div>
                </div>

              </div>

            <div class="row" id="showgroup">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">User Group
                   <span class="required"> * </span>
                  </label>
                  <select class="form-control bs-select" id="userGroup" name="userGroup">

                  <?php 

                    $select_group_query="SELECT group_id, group_name FROM user_group";  
                    $run= mysqli_query($conn, $select_group_query);

                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {     

                        echo "<option value= '".$row['group_id']."' >" . $row['group_name'] . "</option>";

                    }

                  ?>  

                  </select>

                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id"/>


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn blue" onclick='UpdateUserDetail()'>Aggiorna</button>


  </div>
  </form>

  </div>            

  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the php**

```
require_once('../../../config/config.php');
$user_email = $_GET['userEmail'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $query = "SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_id NOT LIKE ? ";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $user_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $times[] = $row['user_email'];
    }
    if(in_array($user_email, $times)){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
```

**this is the javascript**

```
 function GetUserDetail(id) {

    $("#user_id").val(id);

    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

    $.ajax({  

      url:"../controllers/ctrl_admin_user_app/ctrl_admin_get_user_details.php",  
      method:"POST",  
      data:{user_id:user_id},  
      dataType:"json",  


      success: function(data){  

        console.log(data);

       $('#firstName').val(data.user_first);  
       $('#lastName').val(data.user_last);  
       $('#userEmail').val(data.user_email);  
       $('#userTel').val(data.user_telephone);  
       $('#userFiscalcode').val(data.user_fiscalcode);  
       $('#userBirth').val(moment(data.user_birth).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 
       $('#userDocument').val(data.user_iddocument); 
       $('#userRole').val(data.user_role);
       // ricarico il campo per falo funzionare con il plugin bs-select 
       $('#userRole').selectpicker('refresh');

       // Mostro il campo user group solo pe ri clienti e non gli amministratori
       if($("#userRole").val() == "client"){
        $("#showgroup").show();
        $("#showrole").show();
       }else{
        $("#showgroup").hide();
        $("#showrole").hide();
       };

       // $('#userPippo').selectpicker('val', data.group_id).selectpicker('refresh'); 
       $('#userGroup').val(data.group_id);
       // // ricarico il campo per falo funzionare con il plugin bs-select 
       $('#userGroup').selectpicker('refresh');

       $("#EditUserModal").modal("show");

     } 

   }); 

  }



// Funzione per agggiornare i dettagli del cliente lato admin_view_users
function UpdateUserDetail() {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {

      return this.optional( element ) || /^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])$/.test( value );

    };

    $.validator.methods.fiscalcode = function( value, element ) {

      return this.optional( element ) || /^(?:[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z](?:[AEIOU]{2}|[AEIOU]X)|[AEIOU]{2}X|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}[A-Z]){2}[\dLMNP-V]{2}(?:[A-EHLMPR-T](?:[04LQ][1-9MNP-V]|[1256LMRS][\dLMNP-V])|[DHPS][37PT][0L]|[ACELMRT][37PT][01LM])(?:[A-MZ][1-9MNP-V][\dLMNP-V]{2}|[A-M][0L](?:[\dLMNP-V][1-9MNP-V]|[1-9MNP-V][0L]))[A-Z]$/i.test( value );

    };

    // Script per la gestione della validazione form

    $("#formedituser").validate({

      errorElement: 'span', 
      errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', 

      ignore: "",

            // imposto le regole di validazione

            rules: {

              firstName: {

                required : true

              },

              lastName: {

                required: true

              },

              userEmail: {

                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "../controllers/ctrl_admin_user_app/check_email_validation_existing_user.php",
                async: false


              },

              userTel: {

                required: true,
                number: true

              },

              userFiscalcode: {

                required: true,
                fiscalcode: true

              },

              userBirth: {

                required: false,
                dateITA : true

              }

            },

            // mostro messaggi di errore personalizzati

            messages: {

                firstName: "Ops, il campo nome è richiesto!",

                lastName: "Ops, il campo cognome è richiesto!",

                userEmail: {

                    required: "Ops, il campo email è richiesto!",
                    email: "Ops, il formato email non è corretto!",
                    remote: "Ops, questo indirizzo email esiste già, per favore scegline un altro!"

                },

                userTel: {

                    required: "Ops, il campo telefono è richiesto!",
                    number: "Ops, il formato del numero non è corretto!"

                },

                userFiscalcode: {

                    required: "Ops, il campo codice fiscale è richiesto!",
                    fiscalcode: "Ops, non sembra un codice fiscale valido!"

                },

                userBirth: {

                    dateITA : "Ops, Il formato data deve essere nel formato giorno/mese/anno"

                }


            },

            highlight: function (element) { 

              $(element)
              .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); 

            },

            success: function(label) {
              label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
              label.remove();
            },

            // invio i dati del form utilizzando ajax

            submitHandler: function(form) {


              $.ajax({

                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),


                    // se tutto va a buon fine mostro un messaggio di successo utilizzando sweetalert

                    success: function(response) {

                      console.log(response);

                      $("#EditUserModal").modal("hide");

                      swal({

                        title: response.title,
                        text: response.message,
                        type: response.status

                      },

                      function(){ 

                        location.reload();

                      }

                      );

                    },

                    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

                      $("#EditUserModal").modal("hide");

                      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                        swal('Il server non risponde', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                        swal('Errore 404', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                        swal('Errore 500', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {

                        swal('Si è verificato un errore!', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else if (exception === 'timeout') {

                        swal('Time Out', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else if (exception === 'abort') {

                        swal('Richiesta Annullata', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                      } else {

                        swal('Errore non previsto', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');
                      }

                    }  

                  });

                }

          });


    // rimuovo le notifiche di errore
    $('#EditUserModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#formedituser').validate().resetForm();
        $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

    });



});



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to sort it out adding this code to Jquery validation

```
remote: {
                    url: "../controllers/ctrl_admin_user_app/check_email_validation_existing_user.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                      user_id: function() {
                        return $( "#user_id" ).val();
                      }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden field has no value. It should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="$user_id" />
```

Comment: Hi @Faust thanks for your answer the value for the hidden filed is populated by the function GetUserDetail(id) that is fired when i open the modal window. This is what i see using google developer console <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="90">